# simplify for iteration to linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I currently work on a .NET 4.7.1 application. Given is a for loop to compare 2 lists and to check if any Id has changed. If any Id in list 1 is different to any Id in list 2, I need to return null, otherwise the list 2.

I currently solved this issue with a simple for iteration. Nevertheless, I was wondering if I could solve this easier with a LINQ statement.

```
var list1 = new List<string>
{
  "A",
  "B",
  "C"
};

var list2 = new List<string>
{
  "A",
  "C",
  "B"
};

private List<string> Compare(){

 if (list1 != null)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i])
        {
            return list2;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

 return list2;
}
```

Do you know how to solve this instead of a for loop, but with a LINQ statement?

Thanks!

Comment: `List<string> Compare() => list1.Except(list2).Count() != 0 ? list2 : list1;`

Comment: @FCin They seem to want to compare items at the same position which `Except` doesn't do.

Comment: @juharr Yup, you are right, my comment is incorrect

Comment: You should probably include a check to make sure the lists have the  same number of items as well.

Comment: Read up on `Zip`.

Comment: Please show us an example where `list1` and `list2` have different numbers of entries in them, and the entries aren't all the same. Please show **the expected results** also.

Comment: I'd **strongly** recommend not returning `null` when returning lists. Instead, consider returning an empty list.

Comment: code form Q does not match the description, does it?

Comment: Look at `SequenceEqual`, like `list1?.SequenceEqual(list2)`

Comment: " If any Id in list 1 is different to any Id in list 2" that would mean to pass the test both lists have to have a single id in all elements ?=! did I understand you correctly? your code does something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one linq alternative to the For loop

```
   private List<string> Compare()
    {
        if (list1 == null) return list2;
        if (list1.Where((x, i) => x != list2[i]).Any())
        {
            return list2;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where `list1` and `list2` are different lengths, although to be fair the question doesn't say that they can be different lengths.

Comment: didn't know that overload of Where()! `list1.Where((l1, index) => l1 != list2[index]).Any()` would read better,wouldn't it?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander yes, agree!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Zip` to group the items together to compare them, and then `All` to make sure they're the same:

```
private List<string> Compare()
{

 if (list1 == null) return list2;
 if (list1.Count != list2.Count) return null;

 bool allSame = list1.Zip(list2, (first, second) => (first, second))
                     .All(pair => pair.first == pair.second);


 return allSame ? list2 : null;
}
```

NOTE: The `Zip` function is used to place both items into a tuple (first, second).

You can also use `SequenceEqual`

```
private List<string> Compare()
{

 if (list1 == null) return list2;

 bool allSame = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);      
 return allSame ? list2 : null;
}
```

Comment: also upvoted as .Zip was the first which came into my mind when doing sth. on Enumerables with on the same index. But afaik readability is less than the Q's For-Loop (or refactored to a ForEach-Loop

Comment: @Sean but wondering why you want to zip and again compare when you can compare with just one loop, any advantages you see?

Comment: `return allSame ? list2 : null;` Is that what the OP's code does?

Comment: @mjwills - the code is different from the question! The question says "If any Id in list 1 is different to any Id in list 2, I need to return null", whereas the code in his example does the opposite!

Comment: @Sean Given the answer that has been selected, I suspect the code is the accurate indicator of the behaviour they are expecting. But yes, the question is confusing at best.